# I need to search the authors that their titles in their books have the word "computer"in it, but it cant have the plural "computers"

Tags: sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

I tried with the like operator,but it shows singular and plural, What can i put in the where clause to only appears singular "computer"

```
SELECT (AU_FNAME +' ' +AU_LNAME)AS AUTOR, TITLE
FROM AUTHORS
INNER JOIN TITLEAUTHOR ON AUTHORS.AU_ID=TITLEAUTHOR.AU_ID
INNER JOIN TITLES ON TITLEAUTHOR.TITLE_ID= TITLES.TITLE_ID
WHERE  TITLE LIKE ('%COMPUTER%')
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: `AND TITLE NOT LIKE '%COMPUTERS%'` alternatively if SQL Server: `WHERE  TITLE LIKE '%COMPUTER[^S]%'`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda That’s a nice tip for exclusion of the S in SQL Server - didn’t know you could do that.

Comment: @AlexisPerez . . . And what do you want if the string contains both "COMPUTER" and "COMPUTERS".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax suggests SQL Server.  You *could* do:

```
WHERE TITLE LIKE '%COMPUTER[^S]%'
```

but that would miss `COMPUTER` at the end of the string.  One way around that is:

```
WHERE TITLE + ' ' LIKE '%COMPUTER[^S]%'
```

This makes sure that there is an additional character for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
WHERE TITLE LIKE '%COMPUTER%' AND TITLE NOT LIKE '%COMPUTERS%'
```